# Laravel postgres current_timestamp

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, timestamp

Hi I have a problem in current timestamp query I am using laravel and postgres. my query is like this

```
 $min_max_avg = DB::table('token_queue')                             
    ->join('token', 'token.id', '=', 'token_queue.token_id')                             
    ->select(DB::raw('MIN(serving_end_time - serving_start_time) AS min_total_serving_time'))                                                       
    ->whereBetween('token.generated_time',[DB::raw("date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"), 
                                           DB::raw("date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '1 hour')")])
    ->first();
```

which generate sql like this

```
select 
MIN(serving_end_time - serving_start_time) AS min_total_serving_time
from "token_queue" inner join "token" on "token"."id" = "token_queue"."token_id" 
where "token"."generated_time" between date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '1 hour')
```

so when i run this sql in pgAdmin it work fine but it laravel in giving me error
**Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"**

my table are like this

table **token**

```
id       | generated_time
196618   | 2016-10-15 01:02:48.963
196619   | 2016-10-15 01:02:50.569
196620   | 2016-10-15 01:03:12.931
196621   | 2016-10-15 02:03:17.037
196622   | 2016-10-15 02:22:55.782
196623   | 2016-10-15 02:24:57.477
196624   | 2016-10-15 03:23:00
```

table **token_queue**

```
id | serving_start_time      | serving_end_time        | token_id
1  | 2016-10-15 01:02:48.963 | 2016-10-15 01:03:02.69  | 196618
```

thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't think it is generating the SQL that you think it is. I think it is generating a where clause containing placeholders, and then supplying the expressions to the placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Laravel, but a bit of googling gave me the firm impression that DB::Raw would not be respected on the RHS when calling `whereBetween`.

Try using `whereRaw()` to add the where clause that you want in raw SQL.

```
->whereRaw("token.generated_time between date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '1 hour')")
```